# How to write "nested if...else statement for constants" without warnings, in gnu++11 standard?

Tags: c++, if-statement, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

When I use nested if....else statement with

```
if (std::is_same<T, T1>::value) 
{
  // do something
} 
else if (std::is_same<T, T2>::value)
{
  // do something else
}
.
.
.
else
{
  // print error
}
```

I get a QACPP static code analyzer's compiler warning qacpp-4.2.1-4090 with message "The condition in this 'if' statement is constant." How do I fix this compiler warning in gnu++11 standards ?

NOTE: I'm not an expert at C++ so please excuse me if the question sounds amateur.

Comment: Drop QACPP in favor of some other tool?

Comment: Is it a function? What does the signature look like?

Comment: I slightly modified the question, if you see it now, the above lines are called inside the constructor of a template class T and compared with other template types T1, T2 to assign a particular value for a member variable of the template class T, based on the matching if condition.

Answer (score 3):

For a particular instantiation of `T`, the `if` conditionals *are* constant. In other words `std::is_same<T, int>::value` &c. are constant expressions.

But that may well be a necessity if you've set the code out in this perfectly legitimate way. (You might be able to refactor to a static polymorphism technique using template specialisation if obviating the static analyser warning is important.)

Seems that the static analyser is being over-zealous to me.

Comment: Will it be any different if I tell that the actual code does not have ```if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)``` but has ```if (std::is_same<T1, T2>::value)``` ? However I the code analyzer shows warning in both cases.

Comment: There's no difference. This is because `std::is_same<T1, T2>::value` is always a compile time evaluable constant expression.

Comment: Yea, I guess you're right... so there is nothing that can be done to fix such warnings ? NOTE: I use PRQA Source Code Analyzer v2.3.0.93377 Framework.

Comment: @Rookie_Coder2318; Other than changing the warnings or refactoring the code (which I wouldn't do on the grounds that it would be an imperfect tail wagging a reasonably coded dog), no. Static analysers have their place but I don't think the goal is to eliminate all warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The coding tool is literally asking you to abandon good practices like:

```
if (static_condition) {
   // code that is effectively compiled out when static_condition is false
}
```

and instead use something like:

```
#if static_condition
   // code that is compiled out when static_condition is false
#endif
```

which can't even be done in the exact situation you have there, and is an inferior practice.

This is not a good, productive diagnostic, except in cases when `static_condition` is clearly unconditional, like `if (false) ...`.

If the diagnostic tool is otherwise valuable, find out how to suppress that diagnostic in specific files or lines of code. Maybe it supports some directive that can be put into comments to squelch some diagnostics.

```
// @foo-bar tool: disable-warning(13125)
if (static_condition) ...
```